# Dynamically adding select element to form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, select, addition

I've read many posts on dynamically adding fieldsets..But I could not find a solution to my problem.

I've tried this:

```
$('#btnAddField').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#section2').append('<div><select class="form-control" name="rendezo_neve"> \
        <?php 
                $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db("mydb");
                $res = mysql_query("select * from `rendezo` ORDER BY ID DESC");
                if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
                    ?><option value="<?php echo $row["First_Name"] . " " .$row["Last_name"];?>"> <?php echo $row["First_Name"]." ".$row["Last_Name"];?></option><?php
                }
                mysql_close($conn);
        ?>\
        </select><input type="button" value="X" class="remove_field"></input></div>');
    });



    $("#upload").on("click",".remove_field", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
    })
```

The problem is that when I add the new `<select>` element to my form then its empty.

I want to list all the elements from my database as `<option>` everytime when I add new `<select>` element to my form.
Can I do it like above?

Comment: You are using PHP client-side

Comment: You should use AJAX for something like that

Comment: The issue you are facing is that you are trying to combine a server sided and a client sided scripting language. PHP is server sided and is executed before the page finishes loading. Javascript executes after the page has been delivered from the server to the client. Therefore, anything you write in PHP, will never change after the page loaded. To work around this, you need to use ajax or jquery.get() to load the php code from another php file.